# c++ Problema de matrices con funcion entra en loop de carga infinito

Tags: c++, bucle-for, matriz, funcion

Esta es mi primera vez preguntando algo. Estoy aprendiendo c++ y tengo un problema con un ejercicio de matrices, el cual carga por medio de una función que se invoca en un switch. El problema es que al cargar las matrices no finaliza la carga al terminar el ingreso, vuelve a pedir datos. ME gustaria tener una ayuda acerca del problema. El mismo ejercicio sin utilizar funciones resolviendolo en el main lo pude realizar, pero es un ejercicio en el cual debo utilizar funciones. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

```
//###########Carga ininterrumpidamente las matrices

using namespace std;

void cargarMatrices(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3],int filasa, int colsa, int filasb , int colsb);
void sumarMatrices(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa, int filasb , int colsb, int filasc, int colsc);

void restaMatrices(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa, int filasb , int colsb, int filasc, int colsc);

void productoEscalar(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa, int filasb , int colsb, int filasc, int colsc);

void productoMatriz(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa, int filasb , int colsb, int filasc, int colsc);

void salir();


int main(){
    
    int matriza[3][3];
    int matrizb[3][3];
    int matrizc[3][3];
    
    int fa,ca,fb,cb,fc,cc,es;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese el nro de filas de la matriz a: "<<endl;
    cin>>fa;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nro de columnas de la matriz  a: "<<endl;
    cin>>ca;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nro de filas de la matriz b: "<<endl;
    cin>>fb;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nro de columnas de la matriz  b: "<<endl;
    cin>>cb;
    
    
    int opcn;
    
    //Menu
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de operación a realizar \n 1)cargar matrices 2) suma\n 3) resta \n 4) Producto escalar \n 5) Producto de matrices 6)Salir \n"<<endl;
    cin>>opcn;
                
    do{
        switch(opcn){
            
        case 1: { 
        
                cargarMatrices(matriza, matrizb,fa,ca,fb,cb);
                break;
        }
        case 2: { 
                sumarMatrices(matriza, matrizb, matrizc,fa,ca,fb,cb,fc,cc);
                break;
        }   
        case 3: {
                restaMatrices(matriza, matrizb, matrizc,fa,ca,fb,cb,fc,cc);
                break;
        }
        case 4: {
                productoEscalar(matriza, matrizb, matrizc,fa,ca,fb,cb,fc,cc);
                break;
        }
        case 5: {
                productoMatriz(matriza, matrizb, matrizc,fa,ca,fb,cb,fc,cc);
                break;
        }
        case 6: {
                salir();
                break;
        }
        default:
                {
                cout<<"Opcion incorrecta ";
                break;
                }

                        }
        }while (opcn!=6);
    
     getch();
    return 0;
}

    void cargarMatrices(int matriza[3][3],int matrizb[3][3],int filasa,int colsa,int filasb,int colsb){

        
        cout<<"\nCarga de a"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<filasa;i++){
            cout<<"filasa "<<i<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<colsa;j++){
                    cout<<"colsa "<<j<<endl;
                cout <<"Ingrese los valores para a \n"<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<endl;
                cin >>matriza[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        
        cout<<"\nCarga de b"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<filasb;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<colsb;j++){
                cout <<"Ingrese los valores para b \n"<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<endl;
                cin >>matrizb[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        
        /*
        //Muestra la carga de a
        for(int i=0;i<filasa;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<colsa;j++){
                cout <<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matriza[i][j]<<endl;
            }
    
        }
        //Muestra la carga de b 
        for(int i=0;i<filasb;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<colsb;j++){
                cout <<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizb[i][j]<<endl;
            }
        }
        */
        
    }   
    
    void sumarMatrices(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa,int colsa,int filasb,int colsb,int filasc,int colsc){
        if((filasa!=filasb)||(colsa!=colsb)){
            cout <<"Operación inválida";
            }
            
        else{
            filasc=filasa;
            colsc=colsa;
            for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    matrizc[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
            
            for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    matrizc[i][j]=0;
                    matrizc[i][j] = (matriza[i][j] + matrizb[i][j]);
                    cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
                
                
    void restaMatrices(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa,int colsa,int filasb,int colsb,int filasc,int colsc){
    
        if((filasa!=filasb)||(colsa!=colsb)){
            cout<<"Operación inválida";
            }
            
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    matrizc[i][j]=0;
                    matrizc[i][j] = matriza[i][j] - matrizb[i][j];
                    cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }
            cout<<"\n";
            
        }   
    }
        
        
    void productoEscalar(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa,int filasb,int colsb,int filasc,int colsc){
        cout<<"A probar"<<endl;
        int escalar=0;
        cout<<"Ingrese el escalar para multiplicar a la matriz"<<endl;
        cin>>escalar;
        int m=0;
        cout<<"Elija la matriz sobre la que hacer la operación, matriz 1 o 2"<<endl;
        cin>>m;
        
        if (m==1){
            filasc=filasa;
            colsc=colsa;
            for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    matrizc[i][j]=0;
                    matrizc[i][j]+=matriza[i][j] * escalar;
                    cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }
        }
        if (m==2){
            filasc=filasb;
            colsc=colsb;
            for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    matrizc[i][j]+=matrizb[i][j] * escalar;
                    cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }
        }
        //Muestra resultado
        for(int i=0;i<filasc;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<colsc;j++){
                    cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
                }
            }   
    }
    
    
    void productoMatriz(int matriza[][3],int matrizb[][3], int matrizc[][3],int filasa, int colsa,int filasb,int colsb,int filasc,int colsc){
        cout<<"A implementar";
        int m;
        for (int i=0;i<filasa;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<colsb;j++){
                matrizc[i][j]=0;
                for(int k=0;k<colsa;k++){
                    m = matriza[i][k] * matrizb[k][j];
                    matrizc[i][j] += m;
                }
                cout<<"["<<i<<"]"<<"["<<j<<"] : "<<matrizc[i][j]<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }
    
    void salir(){
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\n Ha salido del programa\n";
    exit (-1);
    }
```

Comment: main tiene return 0. La función salir es de tipo void. Cambié el -1 por 0 pero sigue el bucle.

Comment: ¿Qué datos introduces, qué esperabas ver por pantalla y qué ves en su lugar?